# Yum update error: "can't start new thread"

Tags: centos, yum

I found several posts on this, but none of them work.

When I do `yum update`, I get the error **`thread.error: can't start new thread`**; full stacktrace follows:

```
[root@ripper234 ~]# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/yum", line 29, in ?
    yummain.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 309, in user_main
    errcode = main(args)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 178, in main
    result, resultmsgs = base.doCommands()
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/cli.py", line 345, in doCommands
    self._getTs(needTsRemove)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/depsolve.py", line 101, in _getTs
    self._getTsInfo(remove_only)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/depsolve.py", line 112, in _getTsInfo
    pkgSack = self.pkgSack
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 661, in <lambda>
    pkgSack = property(fget=lambda self: self._getSacks(),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 501, in _getSacks
    self.repos.populateSack(which=repos)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/repos.py", line 232, in populateSack
    self.doSetup()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/repos.py", line 79, in doSetup
    self.ayum.plugins.run('postreposetup')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/plugins.py", line 179, in run
    func(conduitcls(self, self.base, conf, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib/yum-plugins/fastestmirror.py", line 181, in postreposetup_hook
    all_urls = FastestMirror(all_urls).get_mirrorlist()
  File "/usr/lib/yum-plugins/fastestmirror.py", line 333, in get_mirrorlist
    self._poll_mirrors()
  File "/usr/lib/yum-plugins/fastestmirror.py", line 376, in _poll_mirrors
    pollThread.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/threading.py", line 416, in start
    _start_new_thread(self.__bootstrap, ())
thread.error: can't start new thread
```

I've already tried `yum clean`, that didn't help.

My OS is Centos 5.5.

Comment: Looks pretty much like python problem.  Why don't you post this to yum bugtracker?

Comment: I've gotten this error when I ran out of memory on a small (64M) VM.

Comment: @barrycarter - me too.

Answer (score 9):

This is mostly an issue with `yum` in CentOS 5.5+ versions and is caused by the `fastestmirror` plugin. One way to bypass is to use `yum update --disableplugin=fastestmirror`.

The best method to use rather than disabling the plugin completely is to reduce the number of threads. To this just edit the `/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/fastestmirror.conf` file and change the value `maxthreads=xx` to a lower value.

My default values were 15 and was giving an error with 150MB+ free RAM; I changed it to 5 and no more troubles.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to disable `fastestmirror` plugin and check if after that change `yum` will be working properly. To disable it do: edit `/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/fastestmirror.conf` and change `enabled = 1` to `0` or just remove plugin package: `yum remove yum-fastestmirror` or `yum remove yum-plugin-fastestmirror`.

Comment: is that a typo?  didn't you mean `remove` instead of `install`?

Comment: Yup. It was typo. Fixed now.