# Yum update/install to any package is giving me the following error. What actions do I need to take to overcome this?

Tags: linux, fedora, yum

Yum update/install to any package is giving me the following error. What actions do I need  to take  to overcome this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/yum", line 29, in <module>
    yummain.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 267, in user_main
    errcode = main(args)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 120, in main
    result, resultmsgs = base.doCommands()
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/cli.py", line 432, in doCommands
    return self.yum_cli_commands[self.basecmd].doCommand(self,     self.basecmd, self.extcmds)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yumcommands.py", line 226, in doCommand
    return base.updatePkgs(extcmds)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/cli.py", line 736, in updatePkgs
    if not self.update(pattern=arg):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 3687, in update
    obs_tups = self.up.obsoleted_dict.get(installed_pkg.pkgtup, [])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 878, in     <lambda>
    up = property(fget=lambda self: self._getUpdates(),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 702, in _getUpdates
    self._up = rpmUtils.updates.Updates(self.rpmdb.simplePkgList(), self.pkgSack.simplePkgList())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/rpmsack.py", line 489, in simplePkgList
    return self.pkglist
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/rpmsack.py", line 232, in _get_pkglist
    csumpkgtups = self.preloadPackageChecksums(load_packages=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/rpmsack.py", line 966, in     preloadPackageChecksums
    rpmdbv = self.simpleVersion(main_only=True)[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/rpmsack.py", line 1149, in simpleVersion
    self._put_cached_simpleVersion_main(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/rpmsack.py", line 1098, in _put_cached_simpleVersion_main
    os.rename(rpmdbvfname + ".tmp", rpmdbvfname)
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4578/yum-update-error-cant-start-new-thread

Comment: Rebuild rpm db if `yum clean all` and disable fastestmirror plugin doesn't work.

Comment: @quanta Okay, will do and post back the result here.

Comment: What did you do before this? Did you a minor release update?

Comment: Disk full? `df -h`

Comment: @Nils Had not used yum before this(yesterday until this installation). A system restart seems to have resolved the problem.

Comment: @Tim The disk certainly was not full. A system restart seems to have resolved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your situation is imho similar to the one outlined in a  [CentOS question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22476/installing-yum-on-centos-5).

So the solution is possibly the same: Reinstall `python`, then reinstall `yum` then do `yum clean all && yum makecache` and afterwards `yum update`.

Comment: A system restart seems to have resolved the problem. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey it seems Michael Hampton got it right. After you accepted his answer you can comment on his answer... did you find any bad sectors?

Comment: A `badblocks /dev/sda` did not yield any bad sectors. Sad, could not determine the root of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The important part seems to be the last line:

```
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

This indicates a physical failure to read or write data from/to the underlying storage medium, i.e. your hard drive.

If you run `dmesg` you may find at the end some further diagnostic information.

Whenever I run into this particular error I immediately become suspicious of the media. Since it's likely a hard drive, you may want to check its SMART status, for example:

```
smartctl -a /dev/sda
```

And check it for bad sectors:

```
badblocks /dev/sda
```

Also check to make sure your drive cable is securely connected and that your power supply is supplying enough power.

Comment: A system restart seems to have resolved the problem. But I am doing a check for bad sectors.

Comment: A `badblocks /dev/sda` did not yield any bad sectors. Sad, could not determine the root of the problem.

Comment: I had a couple of other ideas you may want to check.

Comment: Sure do post them in the answer.. :)